# Do Google Analytics goals, events, or transactions trigger a pageview?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

If I programmatically trigger a goal, event, or a ecommerce transaction on a certain page, does Google Analytics register a page view on the page? (which would show up under Behavior > All Pages for example)

Comment: What have you tried in your testing? Please provide some proof of effort. I'm sure you'll find the answer quite quickly, if you check with Real-time reporting.

Comment: I'm not sure how Real-time reporting applies to other reports. I triggered events in GA via Google Tag Manager, and I think I've seen cases where it fired a pageview even when I didn't explicitly visit the page, which is why I ask. But maybe GTM does something differently or maybe my test was contaminated. I'll test again to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics will only trigger a pageview in the following two conditions:

1. A page view is registered whenever one of the pages on a traditional web site is visited. In other words, if a user takes an action that causes the browser to refresh, a pageview will be counted. Take note, this does not count for single-page (ajax) applications.
2. Additionally, a page view can be manually triggered by issuing `ga('send', 'pageview');` using analytics.js. You can attach this code to nearly any sort of event (including ecommerce transactions).

A pageview will not be registered otherwise.

Read about analyics.js [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages).

Answer (score 0):

With goals it's actually the other way round - a pageview might be defined as a destinantion goal, i.e. the pageview triggers the goal. However the goal is not a pageview by itself, especially since it only exists in the view configuration.

Events and transaction won't show up as pageviews, either - but then thinking in pageviews does not always make sense. It's much better to think of "interactions", people doing something with your page. So an event will not show up in the page content section of your report, but it is still an interaction that shows up in the behaviour/events report and may e.g. have influence on your bouncerate. PLus any interaction will count towards your hit quota (free version of GA is limited  to 10mio user interactions per month).